# Find optimum values for a function result satisfaction

Tags: functions

Lets say I have a function $\frac{x\cdot e_1 + y\cdot e_2}{z\cdot e_3}$. And I fill this function with random values $\frac{10\cdot 2 + 12\cdot 3}{2\cdot 2}$, so $x=10$, $e_1=2$, $y=12$, $e_2=3$, $z=2$ and $e_3=2$. What I want now to do, is to change all these values (add or substract) by some factor (for example $0.5$), so the function result nears to $0$. And I want to do it an a way, that $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are as low as possible and the steps I need to take a few as possible. So how to I approach this?

Comment: Do you need to modify *all* the variables in the same manner?

Comment: @Patricio ok `x,y,z` I can add or substract by some constant, like 0.5. `e` values change imminently to something different.